# vt.net, How to populate a combobox with a text file?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, combobox, text-files, streamreader

I'm using Visual Basic 2010 and I need to populate a combobox with a txt file.

I'm trying with Streamreader, but I can't figure it out.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
Private Sub FillComboFromFile(ByVal path As String)
  Try
    If IO.File.Exists(path) Then
      Using sr As New IO.StreamReader(path)
        While Not sr.EndOfStream
          ComboBox1.Items.Add(sr.ReadLine)
        End While
      End Using
    Else
      MsgBox("Oooops, File not found !!!")
    End If
  Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
  End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Or this:

```
ComboBox1.Items.AddRange(IO.File.ReadAllLines(path))
```